# Function issue. Tidyeval filtering

Tags: r, function, dplyr, nse, tidyeval

What is wrong here? This works:

```
iris %>% 
  filter(Species == "setosa") %>% 
  summarise(msl = mean(Sepal.Length), msw = mean(Petal.Width))
```

and produces:

```
    msl   msw
1 5.006 0.246
```

But this function doesn't work:

```
means <- function(data, value){
  data <- enquo(data)
  value <- enquo(value)
  data %>% 
    filter(Species == !!value) %>% 
    summarise(msl = mean(Sepal.Length), msw = mean(Petal.Width))
}
```

and `means(iris, "setosa")` produces this error:

> Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
>     no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('quosure', 'formula')"
>   Called from: filter_(.data, .dots = compat_as_lazy_dots(...))

Comment: Why do you do `filter = enquo(value)`? You're not using that `filter` at all. The `filter` a few lines later will be the `filter` function. Or actually, it will be *a* filter function, it could be the one in `dplyr` or it could be the one `dplyr` stomps on or some other function. Make a minimal reproducible example with all the library calls and all the version numbers.

Comment: The version number of tidyverse doesnt show the version numbers of the packages you are actually using. List them. Which packages are you using?

Comment: This is a reproducible example. It is the `iris` dataset that comes with R.

Comment: Just the tidyverse. This is just an example dataset.

Comment: Changed the `value <- enquo(value)` bit. Still the same result. I had originally called it `filter`.

Comment: Why are you enquo'ing the data? Where did you get the idea that that was the right thing to do?Also there is no "just the tidyverse". Your code runs with dplyr and rlang.

Comment: dplyr 0.7.7 rlang 0.2.2 - Idea from articles such as: https://sebastiansauer.github.io/prop_fav/ and https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: By the way, I tried the other combinations of `quo`, not using `!!`, and using `UQ(value)` as well before I posted here.

Comment: This can be done with using tidyeval: `means <- function(data, ...){
  data %>% 
    filter(Species == ..1) %>% 
    summarise(msl = mean(Sepal.Length), msw = mean(Petal.Width))
}`

Comment: @wl1234: I suggest you read more about tidy evaluation https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/getting-up-to-speed.html & https://maraaverick.rbind.io/2017/08/tidyeval-resource-roundup/

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is pretty straightforward, you can't filter a quosure. I don't know why you are enquo'ing your data, but this will get you what you want:

```
means <- function(data, value){

  value <- enquo(value)
  data %>% 
    filter(Species == !!value) %>% 
    summarise(msl = mean(Sepal.Length), msw = mean(Petal.Width))

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.